# Why awk for loop require ENTER key before printing anything?

Tags: for-loop, awk

Program: for_loop.awk

```
{
sum = 0
i = 1
for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
  sum += i;
}
printf "Sum for 1 to 10 numbers = %d \nGoodbuy!\n\n", sum
exit 1
}
```

If I execute above code using **awk -f for_loop.awk** it is waiting for input then if I press ENTER key then only it is showing printf statement otherwise it is waiting for my response.

This is not happening in while/do while loop. In for loop only it is requiring input from keyboard (ENTER) then only it is showing the output.

Can anybody explain why this is happening? (forgive me any spelling or grammar mistakes)

---

Edit:

One more question related to above problem i.e,

if I remove `exit 1` in that program it is still waiting for my input (Enter Key) and again if I do that it is printing same output as many times as I press (Enter Key) or until Ctrl+D (to exit).

Without loop how it is running infinite times? means if it is executing `exit 1` means it is out of loop but how can it is going back and executing same statements.

Thanks

Comment: You're missing a fundamental aspect of AWK: normal actions are run for each record. If you don't give any records, AWK won't do anything.

Comment: Another thing Ctrl+D = EOF (end of file)

Comment: Echoing,  райтфолд, see my edit for an example.

Comment: @ райтфолд Can you please explain how it is running infinite times without any loop

Comment: There IS  a loop - awks implicit work loop that reads your input line by line (by default) until EOF. Get the book Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your awk program consists of a single action that will be triggered by each line of input.  When you press ENTER you trigger that action with the first, albeit empty, line of input. You print the sum from 1 to 10 as expected, and then the `exit` statement quits the program without trying to read any more input.

That answers your question, but I suspect you have more in mind that you'd like to work out.  Update your question (or start a new one) if you like and we'll try to help more!

**EDIT**
As mentioned in the comments, the fundamental aspect of awk is that the normal actions are run for every line of input, without having to explicitly do the looping yourself. Play with this example and/or take a few minutes with an online tutorial to get the idea:

```
BEGIN { print "do this once before reading input" }

{ print "do this for each line of input (now processing '" $0 "')" }

END { print "do this once after reading all input" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you run your code in a `BEGIN` block, awk will be waiting for input:

Example:

This waits for input:

```
awk '{print "hello world!"}'
```

This does not:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "hello world!"}'
```

So to fix your code:

```
BEGIN{
    for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
       sum += i;
    }
    printf "Sum for 1 to 10 numbers = %d \nGoodbye!\n\n", sum
    exit 0
}
```

Comment: If I run _awk 'END{print "hello world!"}'_  it is printing **"hello world!"** only when I do **`Ctrl+D` (exit the program)** otherwise it is still waiting....

Comment: my bad, it should be `BEGIN` got mixed up

Comment: If I enter BEGIN loop it is working fine but I think BEGIN and END serve different purposes, mostly I write my code in between these two loops and I stuck why it is require **enter key** and how it is running infinite times _without loop_

Comment: BEGIN {} runs before input, END{} after input.  if you only have BEGIN it does not wait for input

Comment: @phani Using the `BEGIN` block is fine for what you are doing. Don't miss the `exit` statement after the loop.

Comment: Only old, broken awk requires the `exit` statement at the end of BEGIN in this case, all other awks are sensible enough to not wait around for input when there is no script to do anything with that input.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run awk without any input files.

If you type the following command line: **awk ’program’**

awk applies the program to the standard input, which usually means whatever you type on the terminal. This continues until you indicate end-of-file by typing Ctrl-d. (On other operating systems, the end-of-file character may be different. For example, on OS/2, it is Ctrl-z)

---

(Source: GAWK: Effective AWK Programming by Arnold D. Robbins)